# Error while loading a tagger (probably missing model file)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, stanford-nlp

I am creating an Android App in Android Studio where I use Stanford Core NLP and Jetpack Compose. I have been looking for hours in this platform to see if someone has a similar problem like me, but I have not found it.
I use the Stanford 4.5.4.jar, the Stanford Models 4.5.4.jar, and the Stanford Models Spanish 4.5.4.jar. I am storing them in a source directory called libs in the app folder in the view project .

[image]

```
fun analyzeAndDisplayTree(sentence: String): String {
    try {
        // Configurar el pipeline
        val props = Properties()
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, parse")
        props.setProperty("tokenize.language", "es")
        props.setProperty("pos.model", "libs/stanford-corenlp-4.5.4-models.jar")
        props.setProperty("parse.model", "libs/stanford-corenlp-4.5.4-models-spanish.jar")
        val pipeline = StanfordCoreNLP(props)

        // Procesar la oración y mostrar el resultado
        val document = pipeline.process(sentence)
        val parsedSentence = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation::class.java)[0]
        val tree: Tree = parsedSentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation::class.java)

        return "Sentence: $parsedSentence\nParse Tree: ${tree.pennString()}"
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return "Error: ${e.message}"
    }
}
```

And this is where I display it using Jetpack Compose

```
val analysedSentence = Syntax().analyzeAndDisplayTree(text!!)
Text(text = analysedSentence, modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp).weight(0.25f))
```

However although I do not have any internal error, when I run the app and press the button that triggers the Stanford action, I get this errorr -> Error while loading a tagger (probably missing model file)

It will be pleasing if someone could help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly this means that the tagger model file is not present at runtime on the path specified. At runtime, does the path you give: `libs/stanford-corenlp-4.5.4-models.jar` work to access the POS tagger model file? Maybe you could try to check that first with something like outputting `new File("libs/stanford-corenlp-4.5.4-models.jar").canRead()`?

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate it. I have just added a function to check what you have told me. The result was "File is not readable".  Where will you reccomend me to import the .jar files?

Comment: Commonly the easiest approach is to have a models `.jar` file (either the whole original one, or a subset that has what you need) on the CLASSPATH and then the CoreNLP software will be able to find and use any resources in it. If using the provided `stanford-corenlp-4.x.y-models.jar`, the path to give for the English tagger is: `edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger`. In general, you can see what the paths are with `jar -tf stanford-corenlp-4.5.5-models.jar` (or the variant for whatever version you are actually using).